# How to capture process cpu,memory utilization using open source tool

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, performancecounter

I would like to capture the CPU,memory,thread counts of my application process over a period time,to analyse the if any process is using more cpu,memory consumption.
How can we acheive this .

Comment: for windows machines, you can use PerfMon, for Linux machines, Nmon. both are free tools.

Comment: This is exactly explained here - using open source tools.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-server-performance-monitoring-with-collectd-influxdb-grafana/

Answer (score 10):

Check out [PerfMon](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/), it is free and open source.

The usage is pretty straightforward:

1. Download and install [PerfMon Server Agent](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonAgent/) to the host(s) which you need to monitor and launch it.
2. Install Perfmon Metrics Collector plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
3. Configure it to collect the metrics you would like to visualize
4. Start your test.

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) guide for more detailed explanation on the plugin itself and its usage.

Answer (score 2):

For `Windows` machines - [PerfMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb490957.aspx) tool, which is built-in tool in Windows OS.

References:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645516(v=vs.71).aspx
2. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749115(v=ws.11).aspx
3. [JMeter plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) - a plugin for JMeter instead of seperate tool.

---

For `Linux` machines - [Nmon](http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php)

1. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-analyze_aix/

we have [Nmon Analyser](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Power%20Systems/page/nmon_Analyser) which uses `.nmon` file as input and generate graphs for CPU, Memory, Disk, Network, Process etc using `Microsoft Excel`.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly explained here - using open source tools.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-server-performance-monitoring-with-collectd-influxdb-grafana/

JMX monitoring:

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmx-monitoring-using-collectd-influxdb-grafana/